# Проблемы с дискретной видеокартой

Tags: windows

Дискретная видеокарта не работает. Она отображается в диспетчере устройств и задач, но при попытке в последний раз запустить программу, которая требует дискретную видеокарту, приложение просто закрывалось без ошибки. Я пробовал обновлять драйвера и удалять устройство из диспетчера, но ничего не помогает. При работе ноутбука от интегрированной видеокарты все работает исправно. Вот скриншоты с bluescreenview. В остальных дампах файлы те же
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда то мне для работы программы видеомонтажа на ноутбуке пришлось перевести его в "High performance mode" и еще как то пошаманить, чтобы умная Windows не запрещала приложению работать с картой "для экономии батарейки". Может, у Вас то же самое?

Comment: Такие *загадки* решаются методом исключения. В данном случае, самым простым может быть исключение операционной системы - загрузиться со флешки (можно даже в линукс), подгрузить драйвер и проверить карточку там.

Comment: @S.H. я в электропитании подлкючил через powershell максимальную производительность и выставил